# Cant get `7 hours (time) * 10 (financial) to = 70` in excel / google drive spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Im trying to multiply hours * an hourly rate in a google drive document (ive tried this in excel and get the same issue).

What im trying is :

```
7 hours (formatted as Time) * 10 per hour (formatted as financial)
```

This should give me `70` But instead its coming out with `4.67`.

I know its something todo with the way its reading the time, but cant work it out, any ideas ?

Ive created an example google drive spreadsheet of the issue here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sVCVJfnCPk3V9Sm_ZRAyuD-wFwdg02MC95yXjQXq65s/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiply final formula by 24:

`=B1*B2*24`

`07:00` is a formatted time, actually this is `1/24`

Some info about date and time formats here:

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/date-time-formats.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `HOUR()` function to convert the time to hours:

```
=Hour(time)
```